# Android Radio Buttons

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an android application and have run into a slight problem. On certain questions when a user clicks either yes or no followed by the next button they need to go to a different page, however my code seems to be incorrect can someone please help.

Thanks in advance.

below is my code:

```
 public void Next_Btn3(View view){
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton)view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.Yes_3:
            if (checked)
             new Intent(this, Questionnaire4.class);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.No_3:
            if (checked)
                new Intent(this, Questionnaire6.class);
             startActivity(detailIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How To Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As of now, it's very hard to know what the problem is, what the actual and expected outcome are, if you had any errors, ...

Comment: what is `detailIntent`? should you maybe do `detailIntent = new Intent(...)`?

Comment: U should use startActivity(new Intent(this, Questionnaire4.class));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you declare an `Intent` without actually assigning it. You also forgot to use brackets around your `if` body. Lastly, you have casted the clicked Button as a RadioButton, which should instead be found using `findViewById(R.id.radio_id_here)` ; Try this:

```
public void Next_Btn3(View view){
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton)view).isChecked(); //MUST FIND RadioButton through ID, not cast clicked Button as a Radio Button
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.Yes_3:
                if (checked) {
                    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, Questionnaire4.class);
                    startActivity(detailIntent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.No_3:
                if (checked) {
                    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, Questionnaire6.class);
                    startActivity(detailIntent);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion however the app crashes during testing. Basically when a user selects a radio button eg. no and they click the next button they should go to the last page of the which is question 6 if they click yes they should go to question 4

Comment: You other mistake is that your view being passed in is the next Button, but in your second line of code, you cast that Button widget into a RadioButton widget. Instead you must find your RadioButton using findViewById(R.id.radio_id_here), and use that to see if it is checked